# static IP for load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have elastic beanstalk service (HTTP) with elastic IP address assigned. 
I need to have service with SSL certificate, so I created app load balancer.

APP Load Balancer (HTTPS) >> EC2 (HTTP)

Is it possible to have public **static IP** addresses for my HTTPS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you are terminating SSL on your load balancer this is not possible.

It may be possible to use a Network Load Balancer (NLB) with a proxy behind it which would allow you to use static IPs, but this seems overly complicated.  Why do you need static IPs?

The architecture would look like:

NLB --TCP--> Proxy Layer --TCP--> ELB(SSL) --HTTP--> Back End

- NLB layer can have static IPs
- The proxy layer (HAProxy) in an autoscaling group forwards connections to the ELB
- ELB does the SSL temination
- Finally, the back end services in their own ASG

I'm not sure if this would be possible with Beanstalk though.

Comment: it is required from other company (SSL + static IP). NLB is not option I think because I can't use SSL with it.

Comment: You will then have to terminate SSL on the instance(s).

Comment: You can absolutely use SSL with NLB - NLB just don't do it for you.